# Rest API fetch data with complex filter

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I have a rest api for getting resources but I allow complex filter conditions all database SQL filters (like,join with other resource, filter based on operators >,<,in,eq,not eq etc).
Providing these filters in query parameters is not easy.

If I use Post with body to get content with such complex filters, will it be recommeded? What are the drawbacks of using post for getting content ?